# how to create one table which is composed of two diffrent tables

Tags: mysql

I have two table with different structure. like these:

**table1**:

```
+-----+--------+---------+
| id  |  name  |  color  |
+-----+--------+---------+
|  1  |  peter |   red   |
|  2  |  john  |   blue  |
|  3  |  jack  |   balck |
+-----+--------+---------+
```

**table2:**

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| id  |  name  |   age  |
+-----+--------+--------+
|  1  |  alvin |   12   |
|  2  |  caden |   34   |
|  3  |  bacon |   17   |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

Now I want to create a new table with this structure: (**I want this structure**)

```
+-----+--------+----------+-------+
| id  |  name  |   color  |  age  |
+-----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1  |  peter |   red    |       |  
|  2  |  john  |   blue   |       |
|  3  |  jack  |   black  |       |
|  4  |  alvin |          |   12  |
|  5  |  caden |          |   34  |
|  6  |  bacon |          |   17  |
+-----+--------+----------+-------+
```

I can do that via `join`, but there is a problem: **duplicate columns**.

here is my try:

```
create table newtable as
select table1.id, table1.name, table1.color, table2.id, table2.name, table2.age
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

But the **output** will be like this:

```
// This is not what I want ...
+-----+--------+----------+------+--------+-------+
| id  |  name  |   color  |  id  |  name  |  age  |
+-----+--------+----------+------+--------+-------+
```

Also I can use of `union all`, But in this case, I need to both `color` and `age`. Anyway, There is any suggest ?

Comment: based on your sample tables, you would probably want to throw away the original id, and maybe try to join on name instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a union...

```
SELECT id, name, color, null as age From table1
UNION
SELECT id, name, null AS color, age From table2
```

here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2584/3

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) from the Manual page, if necessary.

```
create table table3
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    color varchar(50) null,
    age int null
);
```

**Option1:**

```
insert into table3 (name,color,age)
select t1.name, t1.color, null
from table1 t1
union
select t2.name, null, t2.age
from table1 t2
```

**Option2:**

```
insert into table3 (name,color,age)
select distinct inr.name,inr.color,inr.age
from
    (
    select t1.name, t1.color, null as age
    from table1 t1
    union
    select t2.name, null as color, t2.age
    from table1 t2
    ) inr
```

Something like that.

Comment: the output of your code will be just 3 rows. I want to 6 rows. Each `name` must be a separate line

Comment: there, it is now safe for no duplicates on name (option 2)